# How to generate multiple 3D Coordinates with noise

Tags: noise, unreal-blueprint, simplex-noise, noise-generator

I am currently trying to generate a 3D planetary map like No Man's Sky does using the simplex noise plugin in unreal engine blueprints. How can i generate coordinates for the individual planets?

I already tried to create 3 for loops and get the noise value on the specific coordinate. When the noise value exceeds a threshold a planet is spawned. This works fine, but is very recourse intensive and will group them in non-random patterns.
Is there a better way to get one/multiple coordinates using noise? 
Like a reversed noise function where you enter a threshold and it outputs coordinates? Or maybe a different way?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no such thing to get vertices out of a noise function directly. A noise function produces a single noise value not vertices.

No Man's Sky is using Voxels to generate levels.

A voxel is basically a single point value in a uniform 3 dimensional grid.

For example in minecraft each cube is a  voxel. Voxels with a value 1 is surface and each voxel with a value 0 is air.

They generate floating values between 0.0-1.0 using multiple layers of noise functions. Indeed it's a very complex system and is quite an achievement to have it perform fast enough for a game.

There let's say 0.0 would mean no surface and 1.0 would mean solid surface.

Then they extract the polygons and vertices from the voxel field with something like surface nets or marching cubes. I'd look into one of those algorithms. There are plentiful of resources on this topic.

However you all current tech on this subject are pretty slow compared to the detail and scale in no man's sky.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I already managed to generate terrain using noise functions and marching cubes, the algorithms are awesome, ik :D

Comment: But what i would like to create is something like a galactic map with thousands of stars (points floating in space). To place these stars i need some coordinates. Now my question was if there is an easy way to get "high value" coordinates out of a noise function. Right now i am just using 3 for loops, try for the value at that specific position, add the star if the value is high enough and offset it by a random noise vector (3 different noise functions.) Here is an example of my work, but you can see quite a bit of popping. That's why i would like to know if there is a more efficient way :)

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TDlrq7gzxxs&feature=youtu.be

Comment: You'r current approach is the best approach in my knowledge. You'd have to input a coordinate for a noise to get an output in your scenario and then you receive a value. If the value is high or low enugh there is a star or if you were making a terrain genetation then it would be surface.

Comment: So the surface in your case would be a star and your current approach is the one everyone would use to generate a galaxy

Comment: Also you could apply multiple layers of noise with distortion to generate a sort of milkyway galaxy shape